# How to read content out of a Json file from Javascript with php without Access-Control header

Tags: javascript, php, json

Hey im very new to web developing and i have a big problem.
Im trying to write a javascipt script which does a jquery getJSON request to a php file which then reads out the content of a JSON file and echos them back to the javascript. Now im getting a access-control-origin-header. I don't want to change the header. Is it somehow possible to read the contents of a json file with javascipt? I am the one writing the json file so is it not possible to give everyone access to that one file?

Comment: Why use php at all? JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation iow it is native to JavaScript. If your JSON object starts with a variable name then you can use the script tag to load the file.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending a request to the other origin from client-side, have the getJSON() function call a URL on the same origin. From this endpoint some server-side code can call your PHP script on the other origin and return the result back in it's response.

Comment: Thanks but the Problem is That People will include a Script in their site which needs access on this json file

Comment: Ah so the question is 'Can javascript load resources from other origins where the origin server does not allow cross origin requests?'. No, not not for any browsers that people typically use unless users install browser extensions to disable CORS controls - guess that would be out of the question. Since it seems that you have control of the origin server why not send the appropriate CORS header?

Comment: Thanks for the Answer! It Seems like I don't really know what CORS header does. I always thought it's a header you set in your Apache configuration and then the specified Origins have access to all files on this subdomain. Wouldn't it be useless if you could send the header with your javascript request so everyone sending a request can bypass it? Or am I missunderstanding you?

Comment: Yes that's roughly it. Suggestion was to send the access control header with the response from the server running the PHP script - I know you said you don't want to do that in your question just questioning why not? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: Because there is no php script, that runs. So there is only the Json File and the javascript script which the people who want, can include in their website and the javascript then requests the values from the Json file. Do you mean to do an Ajax Request to a php script which then echos the values back to javascript and at the start of the php script is something like header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"); ? I tried that earlier, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Options are use a proxy to fetch the data, look into JSONP, or use PHP or whatever server side language on the server with the JSON file to provide a response containing the data with appropriate headers. Do some research into these and ask a more specific question if still having troubles.